# Интерпретация confusionMatrix в R

Tags: r

Помогите пожалуйста интерпретировать результаты, которые выдает функция confusionMatrix
В классическом исполнении мы должны получить таблицу верных ответов и результатов

```
               Факт
Предсказание    1    0
            1  TP    FP
            0  FN    TN
```

Содержание целевой переменной в моем случае

```
table(test_2$BOUGHT_FLG)

   0    1 
2316   22
```

Обучив модель я запустила

```
confusionMatrix(test_2$BOUGHT_FLG, predict(rf_2, newdata=test_2[-134], type = "response"))

 Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 2316    0
         1   12   10

               Accuracy : 0.9949          
                 95% CI : (0.9911, 0.9973)
    No Information Rate : 0.9957          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.791963        

                  Kappa : 0.6228          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.001496        

            Sensitivity : 0.9948          
            Specificity : 1.0000          
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0000          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.4545          
             Prevalence : 0.9957          
         Detection Rate : 0.9906          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.9906          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.9974          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Результат меня смущает
TN -2316
TP -10
По идее, так как позитивных исходов 22, 12  - FN, но из получившейся матрицы следует, что это FP
Ведь я понимаю, что предсказания находятся по вертикали, а факт по горизонтали.
Подскажите пожалуйста где я не права?

Comment: отдельные несвязанные вопросы здесь принято задавать отдельно. я удалил второй из вопросов. если хотите — задайте его отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Фактические значения находятся по вертикали. У вас просто машина выдает столбцы перемешанные местами. 12  - это FP (False positive) Ложно позитивная информация. По факту эти значения ложны, но машина их прогнозирует как 1 - позитивные значения.